# Combine path to an array of filenames in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've a list of files in a Makefile variable. I use it to call a couple of implicit rules.

In shorts:

```
 CHAPTERS_FOLDER = chapters
 CHAPTERS := $(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)/lesson1.Md $(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)/lesson2.Md [...] $(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)/lesson23.Md

$(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)/%.Md : %.xml
    mkdir -p $(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)
    pandoc -f docbook -t markdown_strict $< -o $@

$(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)/%.Md : %.odt
    mkdir -p $(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)
    pandoc -t markdown_strict $< -o $@
```

Is  there a way to not have to manually add `CHAPTERS_FOLDER` to each item in `CHAPTER`? Something like a cartesian product of strings or something...

Is there a better way to design these rules to build the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `addprefix`?

```
CHAPTERS = lesson1.Md lesson2.Md lesson3.Md ...

CHAPTER_TARGETS = $(addprefix $(CHAPTERS_FOLDER)/,$(CHAPTERS))
```

Read the first few paragraphs of the manual on [file name functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) to see that they operate on *lists* of file names, not single file names.